# Why does high blood pressure cause tinnitus?

Tags: blood-pressure, blood-circulation, tinnitus, exertion, orgasm-climax

There are multiple reports on the internet where people state that they got tinnitus from high blood pressure. Usually it is related to exertion or having an orgasm.

> Just wondering if anyone has t from high blood pressure? [...]
>   Mine is from excessive orgasm, crazy I know but I think the negative effect of it was major high blood pressure in my head/ ears. [...] I have white noise in both ears, morse cued in both as well as other tones.

https://www.tinnitustalk.com/threads/what-does-tinnitus-from-high-blood-pressure-sound-like.2906/

> When I signed up for workouts at the gym, it made my tinnitus worse and it affected my left ear as well. I was advised not to lift weights and do strenuous activities.

http://forum.bodybuilding.com/showthread.php?t=151353723

I have experienced this effect myself both after having and orgasm and while working out and exerting harder than usual.

I know chronic high blood pressure can cause pulsatile tinnitus, but my question is directed at non-pulsatile tinnitus.

I see multiple possible explanations:
1: High blood pressure elevates the intracochlear pressure. This might cause hearing cells to be compressed to death.

2: High blood pressure restricts the blood flow to the hearing apparatus, which would cause insufficient oxygen supply.